# ListView's getCount() always returns 0

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform, adapter

I'm using `ParseQueryAdapter` to display a `ListView` including the set of elements given by the Parse query:

```
ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<AlertObject> factory =
        new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<AlertObject>() {
            public ParseQuery<AlertObject> create() {
                ParseQuery<AlertObject> query = AlertObject.getQuery();
                query.orderByDescending(AlertObject.TIMESTAMP_KEY);
                query.fromLocalDatastore();
                return query;
            }
        };

alertsListAdapter = new AlertListItemAdapter(activity, factory, thisFragment);
ListView alertsListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.alerts_list_view);
alertsListView.setAdapter(alertsListAdapter);
```

Now, I'd like to know the number of items in the `ListView`, but if I call `alertsListView.getCount()`, it returns `0`. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: someone gave this post a negative vote, but without leaving a comment or a request for clarification. So, I ask for some explanation about the reason of that in order to improve the readability of my question.

**UPDATE**: below my adapter

```
public class AlertListItemAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<AlertObject> {

    private Context context;
    private Fragment listAlertsFragment;

    public AlertListItemAdapter(Context context,
                                ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<AlertObject> queryFactory,
                                Fragment fragment) {
        super(context, queryFactory);
        this.context = context;
        this.listAlertsFragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View getItemView(final AlertObject alertObject, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {
        [...]
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be because you have not added the code for the adapter.

Comment: I've just updated my question! :)

Comment: Can you demonstrate that the query has been executed and contains a non-zero amount of items?

Comment: @ataulm: of course, I have my ListView full of items (33 to be accurate).

Comment: Could you try to add an onClick to one of these list items, which then prints adapter.getCount()? The ListView is not magic - if adapter.getCount() returns zero then there will be zero items. If the onClick item prints non-zero (as I expect) then it's a timing issue (you're calling getCount too early)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect (cannot be sure without seeing the Parse code/docs) that the adapter is not immediately populated with items, and when the query is executed, it'll call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on itself so that the ListView requeries it for item Views.

This would explain why your `getCount()` returns 0 immediately after `setAdapter(ListAdapter)` but why you can also see 33 items.

You can verify this logging `adapter.getCount()` as you do, and in addition, overriding `notifyDataSetChanged` to then observe the order of statements:

```
public class AlertListItemAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<AlertObject> {

    public AlertListItemAdapter(
            Context context,
            ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<AlertObject> queryFactory,
            Fragment fragment) {
        super(context, queryFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.d("FOO", "item count: " + getCount());
    }

    @Override
    public View getItemView(AlertObject alertObject, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d("FOO", "getItemView()");
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

---

If you need to know when the data changes, you can register a dataset changed listener on the adapter:

```
adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        super.onChanged();
        Log.d("Foo", adapter.getCount());
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, maybe this is the issue. However I notice that the debug print, calling ``getCount()``, comes after the items appear in the ``ListView``. For this reason I cannot understand why ``getCount()`` returns 0. I mean, if the print is displayed after the population of the ``ListView``, the adapter should already have items, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, it should. Can you override `notifyDataSetChanged()` to determine the order of calls?

Comment: Before: ``10-11 22:15:43.144 20519-20519/com.goapps.gosafe.pro D/(AlertListItemAdapter.java:183): item count: 26``. After:
``10-11 22:15:43.144 20519-20519/com.goapps.gosafe.pro D/(AlertListItemAdapter.java:185): item count: 26``. It looks like nothing changes before and after ``notifyDataSetChanged()``.

Comment: yeah sorry it wouldn't do, just a bit tired :) You can add a log in `getItemView()` too. You should never get a call in `getItemView()` before `notifyDataSetChanged()` (unless your adapter starts with data, I don't think it does in this case)

Comment: ``Log.d("FOO", "item count: " + getCount());`` is called before several calls of ``Log.d("FOO", "getItemView()");``.

Comment: ataulm, I've noticed your update and I think ``registerDataSetObserver`` is what I need in my case. I've just tried it and works great. Thank you very much, I didn't know that!

Comment: However, the reason why ``getCount()`` returns ``0``, although it is called after the adapter population, remains a mystery! :)

Comment: The `getCount()` at the beginning is normal - when the adapter is set on the ListView, it needs to know whether it has any items before requesting `getView`. I'm unsure why `getCount()` returns 0 after `getView()` has been called though.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you populated your ListView with parse AlertObjects?

I think you should add something like this to your query:

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<AlertObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<AlertObject> alerts, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // Success
                mAlerts = alerts;
                String[] alertObjects = new String[mAlerts.size()];
                Log.v(TAG, "There are " + mAlerts.size() + “ on the parse");
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Log can tell you how many objects you have on Parse.
In this Callback you can populate your ListView and then use

```
.getCount();
```

on your alertListAdapter.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, because if I query my local datastore, the result is exactly a set of AlertObjects. Indeed, if you look at the first part of my code, you can see that the Parse factory creates a ParseQuery of type AlertObject.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply write following line to get number of items in the list view:**

```
int count = alertsListView.alertsListAdapter().getCount();
```

**After:**

```
alertsListView.setAdapter(alertsListAdapter);
```

So your code will look like:

```
alertsListAdapter = new AlertListItemAdapter(activity, factory, thisFragment);
ListView alertsListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.alerts_list_view);
alertsListView.setAdapter(alertsListAdapter);
int count = alertsListView.alertsListAdapter().getCount();
```

Comment: @f_ficarola show your code, where you are trying to get count of list view.

Comment: P.S. I call ``getCount()`` after ``setAdapter()``

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pass, store, and override the getCount() method correctly.

Please provide the code of adapter class if possible